# Nginx logging to remote rsyslog

Tags: logging, nginx, rsyslog

As nginx 1.7+ supports `syslog`, I tried to aggregate all nginx nodes logs onto a remote rsyslog server. I set the `nginx.conf` with

```
error_log syslog:server=[REMOTE_HOST]:514,tag=nginx;
access_log syslog:server=[REMOTE_HOST]:514,tag=nginx;
```

And on remote rsyslog server, i set a config file with

```
local7.debug            /var/log/nginx/access.log; RemoteFormat
local7.debug            /var/log/nginx/error.log; RemoteFormat
```

But still cannot get log, how to aggregate all nginx `access.log` and `error.log` to separate files `access.log` and `error.log` on remote rsyslog server? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `if` condition. See the [example in doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html):

> The if parameter (1.7.0) enables conditional logging. A request will not be logged if the condition evaluates to “0” or an empty string. In the following example, the requests with response codes 2xx and 3xx will not be logged:

```
map $status $loggable {
    ~^[23]  0;
    default 1;
}

access_log /path/to/access.log combined if=$loggable;
```

My idea: if the message is `loggable` (you can rewrite this `map`) the tag will `nginx-access` and if isn't `loggable` the tag will `nginx-error`. And now you can filter it with `rsyslog` via `tag`.

But if you want only seperate the access and error log you can use different tags:

```
access_log ... tag=nginx-access;
error_log ... tag=nginx-error;
```

Another solution: use `severity`!

Comment: thx for the reply, I will use `severity` instead, for the remote rsyslog server side, how can I configure to separate the received access.log and error.log? Thank you in advance.

Comment: See https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Rsyslog#Severity so I think local7.debug (debug severity) and local7.info (info severity) will right.